# Can you create a sklearn Partial Dependence Plot without train_test_split?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

My question is, is there a way to create these partial dependence plots averaged over each possible train_test_plot combination as opposed to just one selected random_state?

From my understanding, in this example, we're only displaying the training and testing datasets at random_state = 0 as shown here:

```
from sklearn.inspection import PartialDependenceDisplay as pdp

#Define the predictor variables and the response variables
X = data[['feature1', 'feature2']]
y = data['target_var']

#Split dataset into training (80%) and testing (20%) sets
X_train,X_test,y_train_,y_test_ = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.20,random_state = 0)

#Create Random Forest and fit to training data
rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 0)

rf = rf_combine.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = rf_combine.predict(X_test)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))

perm_features = ['feature1', 'feature2', ('feature1', 'feature2')]

pd_plot = pdp.from_estimator(rf, X_train, perm_features, kind='average', ax = ax)`
```